# Drawing a Scrim ("Blurry Transparent Rectangle") Under NSAttributedString Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, nsattributedstring, core-text

I'm putting text on top of various images and came across [this article on overlaying text on images](https://medium.com/@erikdkennedy/7-rules-for-creating-gorgeous-ui-part-2-430de537ba96#c56e) which **suggests putting blurry dark rectangle around the bounds of the text to help it stand out from the image.** Basically, as if the shadow of the text were a rectangle. They call it a scrim.

I tried this first by really blurring the shadow but with thin text it really isn't visible. I figure I need to somehow draw a blurry/shadowy rectangle behind the text. I figure there's some way to draw this with CoreGraphics/CoreText. I'm not very experienced in drawing wit either of these as I've dealt mostly with OpenGL.

Any suggestion for trying to create a blurry rectangular shadow when drawing NSAttributedStrings? Could I somehow make the shadow come from another object like a rectangle without drawing that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a pretty easy way to do this with the CALayer [shadowPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/shadowPath) property. Normal usage looks like this:

```
myLabel.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:myLabel.layer.bounds].CGPath;
myLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 10;
myLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

In your case, it sounds like you want a larger box around your label, so you’ll want to change the rectangle being passed into `+bezierPathWithRect:`. That path is specified in the layer’s coordinate space (i.e. the top-left is 0,0), so if you want a box that starts 50pt to the left of the label and 30pt above, and is 200x100pt in size, you’d do this instead:

```
myLabel.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(-50, -30, 200, 100)].CGPath;
```

…then play with the `shadowRadius` and `shadowOpacity` properties to suit your taste.

Comment: So it seems like for CALayer's you can manipulate an objects shadow with shadowPath. That's really cool! **Only problem for me is that I just have an NSAttributedString which I am calling `drawInRect` on to make a texture for OpenGL. Is there any way I can do it with Quartz calls?**

Comment: It is—see the [Shadows](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadows/dq_shadows.html) section in the Quartz 2D Programming Guide—but it’s more complicated. I’m not sure how you can easily draw a shadow without also drawing the thing that’s casting it.